# How to explode GROUP_CONCAT and add items inside links

Tags: php, mysql, explode, concatenation

I want to make some selection and read from mysql database in php.
I create this query:

```html
$sql0="SELECT descrizioni_marche.Id_marca, descrizioni_marche.Id_categoria,
 marche.ID as id_man,marche.marca as maname ,GROUP_CONCAT(categorie.categoria) as cat,categorie.ID as id_cat
FROM marche,descrizioni_marche,categorie
WHERE descrizioni_marche.Id_marca=marche.ID
AND descrizioni_marche.Id_categoria=categorie.ID 
GROUP BY maname
 ";
```

I want to output some of the categories named "cat" like below:

```html
<a href="product_detail.php?cat='. $row0[ "cat"].'&marca='.$row0["maname"].'"><b>' . $row0["cat"] ."". '</b></a>
```

But because I have used GROUP_CONCAT  all the $row0["cat"] display in one row separated by comma and included in one link. I want them to be in different rows and each one of them  to have a different link. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks!
After I do this according to a comment below:

```html
echo ' <a href="product_detail.php?cat='. $row0[ "cat"].'&marca='.$row0["maname"].'"><b>' . explode(",", $row0['cat']) ."". '</b></a>';
```

The result is:`Array to string conversion in`

Comment: It separates by a comma, so just `explode(",", $row0['cat'])`

Comment: Im editing my question

Answer (score 0):

To print all link at same place

array_walk((explode(',',$row0['cat'])),function($category){
     echo '<a href="product_detail.php?cat='. $category. '&marca='.$row0["maname"].'">**' . $category .'**</a>';
    });